# Excel 2007 VBA - How to delete all row in a spreadsheet excluding the rows in one column

Tags: excel, vba

How can i delete/clear all rows except for one column using excel VBA?

Additional info: i have one column with formulas computing a certain thing using values from other columns which i am importing from access database.

Any work around if i dont want to delete the formula in the one column but want to delete everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SpecialCells` to return only Cells of certain types

To delete all constants use:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
```

Comment: + 1 `.SpecialCells` is the best way to go :)